# Running Google Glass GDK Sample on Android Device/Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to run the Google Glass GDK Samples and test them on android device/emulator. I have followed the steps as mentioned in http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-83-hello-world-using-google-glass/ and am able to launch the "ok glass" screen and also able to get the list of commands on the subsequent screen but am unable to add any new commands. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no emulator available as of now for testing GDK applications. You need to run your app on an actual device.